# Is there any information regarding sending an animated sticker pack to WhatsApp for iOS application?

Tags: ios, whatsapp-stickers

I am developing an iOS application and through this application user can send sticker pack to WhatsApp. In the earlier version, I could send the sticker pack with static image to WhatsApp successfully but I am unable to send animated sticker to WhatApp though WhatsApp supports animated stickers.

I would appreciate to get some suggestion on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Check this reply and follow the thread:

[Enable Animated Stickers](https://github.com/WhatsApp/stickers/issues/661#issuecomment-774371510)

> Android guidelines and code added, but have not turned on ability to
> import on WhatsApp side yet, you can develop your apps. Please don't
> publish your app to apps stores yet as that will create a confusing
> experience for users. More information will come next week.
>
> Thanks all!